# The Auth Callback URL for my draft application it's not being called, in the admin panel it stays forever in installing mode

Tags: oauth, bigcommerce

I created a draft application in my store panel, I added the auth callback and load urls, but when I click to install it, it does not call the oauth url. It's not https, is this a problem, considering it's a draft application?

Comment: It is supposed to be https secured with an SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

We're using a draft application and calling localhost, which is obviously not https and it is working fine. My advice is the problem is probably at the server you have instructed Bigcommerce to point to. Try to access that URL manually or use a service like hurl.it to create the request manually.